# How to set up this ActiveRecord association in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating an app which is used by sales people to track orders. I have 3 models - orders, customers, and users.

The sales people are the users, they enter new orders in to the app, the order belongs to them - for commission and performance tracking purposes.

The order also belongs to a customer and the customer has many orders

What's the best way to set up these associations and what are the methods I could then use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have not subclasses your customers/user models in any way. If this is not true please let me know.

Associations in models:

Order

```
belongs_to :customer
belongs_to :user
```

Customer

```
has_many :orders
```

User

```
has_many :orders
```

Instance association methods:

```
order.user
order.customer
customer.orders
user.orders
```

For details please review the [Active Record Association Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for all the association methods that will be available.